# How to view records deleted using batch actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I'm using Active Admin for my application. There is an option to delete record using Batch Actions. I want to show all the record that I've deleted using batch actions on my list.

Is there any way possible to modify the code of batch actions so that the deleted records can be viewed?

This is the code that I'm using for destroy option.

```
batch_action :destroy, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete these records?" do |ids|
      record_ids = Application::Record.where(id: ids).pluck(:record_id)
      Application::Record.where(id: record_ids).destroy_all
      
      redirect_to record_path, :notice => "Successfully destroyed records"
    end
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Code seems reasonable. Does it not work? Is it incomplete? You could include record_ids in the redirect notice, but I assume you want something more?

Comment: The code works fine but I want to modify it so that it can works like soft deletion without act_as_paranoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [active_admin_paranoia](https://github.com/raihan2006i/active_admin_paranoia) I'm not sure how actively maintained it is but the code is quite readable.